# Embedded Youtube Video in an XSL file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

So I have an XSL file and I'm wanted to have an embedded youtube video to display and play on the same page without taking me to youtube. I have the embedded code and I've tried to use the [XSL embed template example](https://gist.github.com/bzerangue/1903640#file-video-embed-xsl). 
[NOTE: I have put in my values for each param]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:param name="contextPath">CONTEXT_PATH/</xsl:param>
    <xsl:include href="xhtml.xsl"/>
  <xsl:variable name="site" select="/home/tree/path/node[2]/@name"/>
    <xsl:template match="home">
        <xsl:element name="div">
            <xsl:attribute name="id">content-type</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">home</xsl:attribute>

          <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="$site='Chameleon'">
            <xsl:call-template name="video-media">
                <xsl:with-param name="width" select="640"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="height" select="348"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="element" select="video-url"/>
            </xsl:call-template>



            <xsl:template name="video-media">
                <xsl:param name="element" select="video-url" />
                <xsl:param name="width" select="640"/>
                <xsl:param name="height" select="348"/>
                <xsl:param name="color" select="'ffffff'"/>
                <xsl:param name="title" select="'0'"/>
                <xsl:param name="byline" select="'0'"/>
                <xsl:param name="portrait" select="'0'"/>
                <xsl:param name="frameborder" select="'0'"/>
                <xsl:param name="video-id">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="contains($element,'youtube.com/watch?v=Bctaf7alxpE')">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($element,'youtube.com/watch?v=Bctaf7alxpE')"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="contains($element,'youtube.com/v/Bctaf7alxpE')">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($element,'youtube.com/v/Bctaf7alxpE')"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="contains($element,'youtu.be/Bctaf7alxpE')">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($element,'youtube.com/watch?v=Bctaf7alxpE')"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:param>

                <div class="video-container">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="contains($element,'youtube.com') or contains($element, 'youtu.be')">
                            <iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Bctaf7alxpE" frameborder="0">
                                <xsl:comment> You Tube Player </xsl:comment>
                            </iframe>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </div>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:when>

       <xsl:when test="$site='anotherSite'">
        <!-- Does Something Different here... -->
       </xsl:when>

       <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- Perform a default action here .... -->
       </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>

     </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, I keep getting errors from my server logs stating:

[CATALINA.OUT LOG]

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR:  'null'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
```

[My Application LOG]

> 2014-09-11 17:28:41,731 WARN com.[My Application/Project Tree] - missing parameters so cannot look for page

I'm not really worried about the logs but the fact that I'm getting a null is really depressing because I've assigned a value to every parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing a complete, minimal example of your problem, it's hard to say for sure, but here are a couple possibilities given the XSLT fragments you did post:

1. Make sure that `xsl:call-template` is not a child of
   `xsl:stylesheet`.  Perhaps you have it right in your original code,
   but it's not clear given the way your code fragments are posted in
   the question.
2. You cannot have both a `@select` attribute and a child element
   (`xsl:choose`) for the `video-id` parameter.

Either of these two mistakes could be causing your XSLT compilation to fail.

### Update per OP edit of XSLT code:

There are more basic errors in the newly posted code:

1. `</xsl:div>` should be `</xsl:element>`.  (BTW, `<xsl:element
   name="div">...</xsl:element>` can be simplified to `<div>...</div>`.)
2. `<xsl:template name="video-media">...</xsl:template>` has to be
   moved to be a child of `xsl:stylesheet`.

Comment: So you're saying that 'xsl:call-template' should be called before xsl:stylesheet? @kjhughes

Comment: I would note that based on the fragment shown, the template "video-media" is being called with "width", "height" and "element" and nothing more. The rest of the param's are not being passed in.

Comment: No, `xsl:stylesheet` is the root element; no elements come before or after it. I mean that `xsl:call-template` should be placed within another named or matched template (e.g. `<xsl:template match="/">` ***here*** `</xsl:template>`).

Comment: @KevinBrown I also tried to comment out the other irrelevant params that were not being called in the `<xsl:call-template>` However I'm still getting the error that it's missing some parameters. I've improved the edit and added more than the previous fragment to make it much clearer. do not worry about the other `<xsl:when` conditions, They work perfectly fine, it's this template I'm battling with.

Comment: The thrashing from basic error to basic error would be better be eliminated via review of introductory XSLT materials; this will be my last round addressing this question.  Thanks.

Comment: @kjhughes I was typing in as I was editing this question. Amazing what silly mistakes you can do when you don't have auto-complete. In regards to moving the `<xsl:template>` and making it a child of `<xsl:stylesheet>`seems to have done the trick. Therefore by calling the template within the `<xsl:when test="$site='Chameleon'">` will allow it to go off and look for the template given the template name !! Thanks for that !! @kjhughes

Answer (score 0):

Solved it !!!

The `<xsl:template name="video-media">` template must be a child of `<xsl:stylesheet>`. However, in a different template called `<xsl:template match="home">` I wanted to call the `<xsl:template name="video-media">` template to allow the embedded video to play within `<xsl:template match="home">`template.

This then was achieved by the code: 
`<xsl:call-template name="video-media">`, given the parameter values in the `@select`

Appreciate the help !!